# Java - Extracting Substrings Programmatically

Tags: java

I am trying to create a code that accepts a user's full name and returns first and last names and initials. Since a user's name length varies, I did not want to use hard coding, so I extract names and initials programmatically. 
However when I run it and enter a name, I get the following error message:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1`

I looked into my code carefully and cannot see where exactly I miscalculated on the index range. I tried to find similar questions here, but though I did see similar problems, they have to do with C++ or Perl, not Java.

```
package nameSubstring;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameSubstring {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /*
         * This is a program that accepts a user’s full name as a string (e.g. Margaret Thatcher) and displays to the user his/her first name, last name and initials in the following format:
           Your first name is Margaret and your last name is Thatcher and your initials are MT.
             */

        System.out.println("This program will take your full name and display your first name, last name, and initials.");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        String firstName, lastName, firstNameInitial, lastNameInitial; 
        System.out.println("Please enter your full name, e.g. Jane Smith:");
        String fullName = scanner.next();
        int nameSpace = fullName.indexOf(' '); 
        firstName = fullName.substring(0, nameSpace); 
        lastName = fullName.substring(nameSpace)+1; 
        firstNameInitial = firstName.substring(0, 1);
        lastNameInitial = lastName.substring(0, 1);
        System.out.println("Your first name is " + firstName + ", " + "your last name is " + lastName + ", " + "and your initials are " + firstNameInitial + lastNameInitial + ".");

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of index you can use String split(), like fullName.split(" "). Therefore, It will have array of values.

Comment: Something to consider: [Personal names around the world](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-personal-names)

Comment: Side point: do not use the term "Java script" in this context.. This is not a Java script; it is a Java program. JavaScript is a completely different language.

Comment: @FredK, good point. Thanks for noting this. I'll try to refrain from using script in the context of Java to avoid confusion with JavaScript.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks for recommending and posting the "name convention" article! It was very interesting and informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) use [`nextLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()):

```
String fullName = scanner.nextLine();
```

and correct the error with the `+1` which must be inside the parenthesis:

```
lastName = fullName.substring(nameSpace+1);
```

Comment: thank you so much!!! Your corrections solved the problem, and I almost feel like an idiot for not realizing what was wrong. I REALLY appreciate your prompt help.

Comment: No need to *feel like an idiot*. These are errors everybody does when starting something new. Just remember that debugging and reading the documentation is the only way to learn (apart from SO of course).